# Shape transformation - circular section

Tags: javascript, matrix, kineticjs, transformation

Is there any simple transformation (transformation matrix...) that will transform section `A` into section `B`? The only requirement is that both sections should have the same size `X`.

I plan to fill section `A` with an image and then to transform it into section `B` including the image. Right now I use javascript `KineticJS` but I am willing to change the framework if necessary.

Is that doable?

[image: Section A transformed to section B]

Comment: Just to clarify, you want the result to be contained entirely in B, not in the combination of A+B?
If you want A+B, you could translate to the centerpoint of wedge-A and then scale by the proportion of (outsideRadiusA-insideRadiusA)/totalRadius. If you want only B, then without your requirement that x-before == x-after, you could just do a scale at the centerpoint. But given your x/x requirement there is no simple transform.  Then you are asking for a combination of scaling and interpolating.

Comment: It should be just B. So you are probably right that there is no simple transformation. How would you do that with scaling and interpolation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is not trivial.

Consider this illustration:

Lines radiate 360 degrees outward from a centerpoint and pass through both arcs A and B.

[image]

This illustration shows many more lines around the centerpoint.

[image]

Think of this as moving every pixel from A to a corresponding pixel in B. This uses linear interpolation (lerping) to move each pixel from A to B.  The total number of colored pixels in A & B are the same--no pixels have been "magically" added to B.

Here’s code for this illustration:

```
var cx=150;
var cy=150;

ctx.lineWidth=1;
for(var a=0;a<Math.PI*2;a+=Math.PI/240){
for(var r=25;r<50;r++){
    var x1=cx+r*Math.cos(a);
    var y1=cy+r*Math.sin(a);
    var x2=cx+(r+25)*Math.cos(a);
    var y2=cy+(r+25)*Math.sin(a);
    ctx.fillStyle="blue";
    ctx.fillRect(x1,y1,1,1);
    ctx.fillStyle="blue";
    ctx.fillRect(x2,y2,1,1);
}
}
ctx.lineWidth=2;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(cx,cy,25,0,Math.PI*2);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(cx,cy,50,0,Math.PI*2);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(cx,cy,75,0,Math.PI*2);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
```

**The problem**

Notice that most of arc A is filled with blue pixels while some parts of B are “moired” (not completely filled).  That’s because  A’s quantity of pixels will not completely fill B’s larger space.

Your image would appear the same.  It would appear "correctly" in arc A but would have missing pixels in arc B.

What you need to do is “fill in the gaps in B” with appropriately determined pixels.

**The solution**

You can do this with an algorithm like bilinear interpolation which fills in the gaps in B by selecting a “best” pixel color.  It does this by comparing 4 adjacent pixels in arc A.  This algorithm enlarges a smaller image into a larger image by filling in "missing" pixels inside the larger space.

You will have to slightly adjust this algorithm to do non-axis-aligned interpolation. Here’s an link to a nice example of bilinear interpolation:

http://strauss.pas.nu/js-bilinear-interpolation.html